# How to match records from incoming webhook with local models records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a webhook that has params I want to match to an existing local models records..

Here's the webhook job:

```
..
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
    shop.with_shopify_session do
      line_items = webhook[:line_items]
      line_items.each do |item|
        variant_id = item[:variant_id]
        product_id = item[:product_id]
      @shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
      @shop_products = ShopProduct.where(shop_id: shop.id)

      @shop_products.each { |s| shop_store_products = s.store_product_id
        if shop_store_products == product_id
          @order = Order.new(store_product_id: product_id, shop_order_id: webhook[:id], location_id: webhook[:location_id], shop_product_id: s.product_id)
          @order.shop_id = @shop.id
          @order.save!
        end
      }
      end

..
```

The webhook comes in fine.  When I remove the `.each` and `if` statement, an Order saves, but all orders will save and I need to filter them to only matching ones as described below..

I only want this to go into my Orders model if the ShopProduct.store_product_id match the incoming product_id

These two should match as when I creat/save the ShopProduct, it brings along a matching product_id.

I have these records existing in my database so that isn't the issue.

Here's my models:

```
**shop.rb**

belongs_to :shop_products
belongs_to :user

**shop_product.rb**

belongs_to :product
has_one :shop
has_one :order

**order.rb**

belongs_to :product
belongs_to :shop_product
```

**Schema:**

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "shop_order_id"
    t.string "shop_product_id"
    t.string "location_id"
    t.integer "shop_id"
    t.string "tracking_numbers"
    t.string "store_product_id"
  end

create_table "shop_products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.string "store_product_id"
    t.integer "shop_id"
  end

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "shopify_domain", null: false
    t.string "shopify_token", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["shopify_domain"], name: "index_shops_on_shopify_domain", unique: true
  end
```

**Goal:** To create an order for each matching product_id to ShopProduct.store_product_id that comes in.

**Question:** How am I able to get my desired results?

For instance, I am unable to retrieve an array of the @shop_product.store_product_id's ... Even in the console i am unable to, it only results something like the folllowing:

```
irb(main):009:0> shop_products.each { |s| sp = s.store_product_id }
=> [#<ShopProduct id: 1, created_at: "2019-06-06 23:45:04", updated_at: "2019-06-06 23:45:04", product_id: 1, store_product_id: "1965852786737", shop_id: 1>, #<ShopProduct id: 2, created_at: "2019-06-07 01:50:15", updated_at: "2019-06-07 01:50:15", product_id: 1, store_product_id: "1234567890", shop_id: 1>]
irb(main):010:0> sp
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):10
NameError (undefined local variable or method `sp' for main:Object)
irb(main):011:0>
```

Shouldn't `sp` be outputting an array of the matching records?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly is that,

```
..
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
    shop.with_shopify_session do
      line_items = webhook[:line_items]
      line_items.each do |item|
        variant_id = item[:variant_id]
        product_id = item[:product_id]
      @shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
      @shop_products = ShopProduct.where(shop_id: shop.id)

      unless @shop_products.blank?
        @shop_products.each do |shop_product|
          if shop_product.store_product_id.eql?(product_id)
            @order = Order.new(store_product_id: product_id, shop_order_id: webhook[:id], location_id: webhook[:location_id], shop_product_id: shop_product.product_id)
            @order.shop_id = @shop.id
            @order.save!
          end
        end
      end
..
```

Comment: Ended up being the product_id coming in through the api was an integer.. and my schema was a string... only took me 5 hours to think of that lmao

Comment: I knew my code was right so it made no sense the entire time.  I kept just retrying the code with minor changes and then realized you can't match records of different records types

Comment: @uno Any reason to  make `store_product_id` as a string data type?

Comment: @uno is there something like that you are saving the intiger value as in string format in `store_product_id` column for example `store_product_id  = "124234234"` ?

Comment: No, no reason, I should change it to a bigint and will soon

Comment: @uno Otherwise you can do so  `shop_product.store_product_id.to_i == product_id`. Hope this will be helpful to you.